# Javascript - How can I check if an element contains an image?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone suggest how I could check if an element contains an image? I'm assuming it would be whether or not it contains the image source but am unsure how to code this.

Comment: I assume you're talking about an `<img>` tag (as opposed to a css background-image).  Correct?  Like you want to see if this div has an img tag: `<div><img src="http://www.blah.com/img.jpg" /></div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the image elemant by using js getElementById then you can easily access the src of that image, which tells you weather element contains image if src is not empty or if contains then src should have image path.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
     var imgSrc = document.getElementById("myImg").attr('src');
     alert(imgSrc);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>My Web Page</h1>

    <p id="demo">A Paragraph</p>

    <img id="myImg" src="http://www.blah.com/img.jpg" onclick="myFunction()"></img>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can do this like so:

```
if( elem.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0) {
    // there is an image
}
```

---

EDIT: After seeing your comment, try this:

```
var imgs = elem.getElementsByTagName('img'), len = imgs.length, i;
for( i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if( imgs[i].src.match(/\/image\.jpg$/)) {
        // the image is there
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I should have been more specific though im looking to see if it contains a specific image. For example does my element contain image.jpg. I have given my images an id is it possible to check if an id is present?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery you can do something like that :

```
if($('#container_id').find('img').length > 0) {
     // Image found on container with id "container_id"
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i have to use Javascript for this. the structure is useful though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work and won't require JQuery like Anael's solution:

```
<div id="test1"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
<div id="test2">Hello</div>    

<script>
function hasImage(id) {
    var childElements = document.getElementById(id).childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
        if (childElements[i].localName != null && childElements[i].localName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(hasImage('test1')); // true
alert(hasImage('test2')); // false
</script>
```

Demo at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLPJC/

Update:

To see if it has a specific `src` try this update:

```
function hasImage(id) {
    var childElements = document.getElementById(id).childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
        if (childElements[i].localName != null && childElements[i].localName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
            if (childElements[i].getAttribute('src') != null && childElements[i].getAttribute('src').toLowerCase() == "img.jpg") {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

alert(hasImage('test1'));
alert(hasImage('test2'));
```

Updated JS Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/qLPJC/2/

Comment: localName is obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/localName

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$("div:has(img)")
```

if you are using jquery